# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 93: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use the tutorium for web https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model and at the step of exporting the trained model, when I typed the code

```
python .\exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\models\my_efficientdet_d1\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\my_efficientdet_d1\ --output_directory .\exported-models\my_model
```

it comes with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\exporter_main_v2.py", line 165, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "d:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "d:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File ".\exporter_main_v2.py", line 156, in main
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), pipeline_config)
  File "d:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "d:\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 93: invalid continuation byte
```

Can someone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: you may have text in different encoding - for code `0xd5` I get `Ő` but in `latin1` or `cp1250` -  `print( b'\xd5'.decode('latin1') )`

Answer (score 0):

Change the folder name "my_efficientdet_d1" in "python .\exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\models\my_efficientdet_d1\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\my_efficientdet_d1\ --output_directory .\exported-models\my_model"
to your actual folder name.
for example, Folder name should be "my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn" in your case.

It should be as below after the modification

"python .\exporter_main_v2.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path .\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn\pipeline.config --trained_checkpoint_dir .\models\my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn\ --output_directory .\exported-models\my_model"

I learned the tf object_detection API from the same link as you did, it should be a typo in the link you post.

[https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#exporting-a-trained-model]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).